# Замена слов во всем тексте на странице. php, mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Помогите пожалуйста.

есть текст (страница) на ней написаны предложения такого типа: *"...это большое предложение DF_HYYU и оно LKIJ_YT и ещё сегодня KIO_UYII...."*

и эти непонятные слова (зашифрованые) (KIO_UYII, LKIJ_YT и т.д.) нужно заменить на слова из огромной таблицы (то есть в качестве примера: в этой таблице есть зашифрованное слово KILOK_UU и его расшифрование - ЗИМА.)

Таблица выглядет так:

```
    -----------------------------------
 id  | name     | text
-------------------------------------
  1 | EX_WORD  |  солнце
  2 | CD_WORD  |  дождь
  3 | KL_IIII | дом
```

В таблице около 4000 строк. т.е. поле **name** - зашифрованное слово, поле **text** - его расшифровка.

Более наглядно. Было предложение:"*Сегодня мне подарили **CV_YTHJU**.*"

И так оно должно выглядеть после замены слова:"*Сегодня мне подарили **МАШИНУ***"

Comment: сначала выгружаем таблицу в ассоциативный массив где ключ - это поле name, а value - text. После в foreach ($mas as $k => $v) { $text = str_replace($k, $v, $text);} где $text - текст для замены, а $mas - полученный из таблицы массив

Comment: Можно написать функцию в базе. Разбиваем строку на токены. К временной таблице токенов строки left-джойнится справочник. Затем через coalesce строится строка. Но это всё настолько сложно, что стоит задуматься, не дешевле ли выгружать всю таблицу замен в php..

Comment: @vp_arth почему бы просто не извлечь из текста зашифрованные слова, сделать выборку по ним, и заменить их

Comment: Да. помогите пожалуйста с написать код.)))

Comment: @teran, а кто его знает - какие слова зашифрованны? Это по всем словам нужно искать. А текст большой) Но в принципе, можно и так.

Comment: @vp_arth дак судя по приведенному тексту, шифрованные слова укладываются в паттерн латинского капса с подчеркиванием. меня больше напрягает, что во фрагменте таблицы все слова в именительном падеже, а вот "подарили _Машин**у**_"